# T4mvc for VB Breaking Everything

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, t4mvc

I've grown an unhealthy dependency on T4MVC since it's such an awesome library i have been using it for years in c# and have never had much of a problem with it

I am working on a new MVC 4 project in VB and it seems to break a lot of my code,  any idea how to fix this i have already tried changing the name of the MVC link generation class in settings but it still seems to be braking a lot of my code it appears to be mostly on the shipped account controller and a few microsoft namespaces anyone had success getting this working in VB

```
Error   6   Type 'ContactsManager.Web.Mvc.LoginModel' is not defined.   C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\AccountController.generated.vb    148 56  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   7   Type 'ContactsManager.Web.Mvc.RegisterModel' is not defined.    C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\AccountController.generated.vb    165 59  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   8   Type 'ContactsManager.Web.Mvc.AccountController.ManageMessageId' is not defined.    C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\AccountController.generated.vb    178 59  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   9   Type 'ContactsManager.Web.Mvc.LocalPasswordModel' is not defined.   C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\AccountController.generated.vb    184 57  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   10  Type 'ContactsManager.Web.Mvc.RegisterExternalLoginModel' is not defined.   C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\AccountController.generated.vb    203 76  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   12  Type 'ContactsManager.Web.Mvc.ContactCreate' is not defined.    C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\ContactsController.generated.vb   260 53  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   13  Type 'ContactsManager.Lib.Models.Web.Address' is not defined.   C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\ContactsController.generated.vb   295 78  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   14  Type 'ContactsManager.Lib.Models.Web.Address' is not defined.   C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\ContactsController.generated.vb   309 104 ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   15  Type 'ContactsManager.Lib.Models.Web.Email' is not defined. C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\ContactsController.generated.vb   330 76  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   16  Type 'ContactsManager.Lib.Models.Web.Email' is not defined. C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\ContactsController.generated.vb   344 102 ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   17  Type 'ContactsManager.Lib.Models.Web.SocialNetwork' is not defined. C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\ContactsController.generated.vb   365 84  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   18  Type 'ContactsManager.Lib.Models.Web.SocialNetwork' is not defined. C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\ContactsController.generated.vb   379 110 ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   19  Type 'ContactsManager.Lib.Models.Web.Phone' is not defined. C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\ContactsController.generated.vb   400 76  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   20  Type 'ContactsManager.Lib.Models.Web.Phone' is not defined. C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\ContactsController.generated.vb   414 102 ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   21  Type 'ContactsManager.Lib.Models.Web.Url' is not defined.   C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\ContactsController.generated.vb   435 78  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   22  Type 'ContactsManager.Lib.Models.Web.Url' is not defined.   C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\ContactsController.generated.vb   449 104 ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   27  Identifier expected.    C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\SharedController.generated.vb 38  30  ContactsManager.Web.Mvc

Error   32  Unable to load referenced library 'C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\Bin\Mono.Math.dll': The system cannot find the file specified. 

Error   33  Unable to load referenced library 'C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\Bin\Mono.Math.dll': The system cannot find the file specified. C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\Bin\Mono.Math.dll 

Error   34  Unable to load referenced library 'C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\Bin\Org.Mentalis.Security.Cryptography.dll': The system cannot find the file specified.    

Error   35  Unable to load referenced library 'C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\Bin\Org.Mentalis.Security.Cryptography.dll': The system cannot find the file specified.    C:\Users\Chris McGrath\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LinqToNextbus\VBATeamAsignment2013\Assignment2-branch-natesh\ContactsManager.Web.Mvc\Bin\Org.Mentalis.Security.Cryptography.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the VB version was not kept up to date with the C# version, so it is based off a much older version of T4MVC. As far as I know, it worked at that time, but I haven't used it myself.

Ideally, we need someone to own maintaining it, but the demand for VB has been limited.

Comment: ya i kinda was thinking that it looked a bit out of date when i was looking to the code and settings files thanks for the info tho it was only for a school project i think can live without it for 1 project